# Video not loading, failed after 2/3 seconrds

Tags: javascript, mediaelement.js

http://florix.net/survey/products/video5/ME/test2.html

The media element library works in Chrome, but not in Firefox. Local setup works on all browsers

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The server sends the file with content-type `text/plain`, configure the server to send `video/webm` instead.

Comment: I can double this, working on Chrome, not working on FF, both on Windows 7. @user1834963 have you tried to configure the server? There is advice on http://mediaelementjs.com/, in the installation section of the page